# Get params as a type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Without using an `object` with `interface` or a full function definition, can a function's parameters be used as a type elsewhere in Typescript much like how `ReturnType<T>` uses return types as type definitions elsewhere? I'd imagine usage such as `InputType` or `ParamType` for this.

For context purposes, take the following example:

```
const x = (y: string, z: string) => ({[y+z]: 3})
```

To use the result of that function (`{string: number}`) as a type we can do `ReturnType<typeof x>`, however can the input parameters be used as an object type (`{y: string, z: string}`), or does the confines of JS's [Array-like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) structure (`[string, string]`) clash with this concept? The use case would be for a container that passes arguments down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript 3.1 introduced the type called `Parameters` that does exactly that.

```
type MyParams = Parameters<typeof x> // [string, string]
```